# Formula to get linear quadratic and interaction terms in R

Tags: r, statistics, svm

I need to fit a linear SVM in R which has one feature as response and the linear quadratic and interaction terms of every other feature in the model as predictors.
Is there a function that helps compute the linear,quadratic and interaction terms of the rest of the predictors(around 15 individual predictors)

Answer (score 4):

**`y ~ .`** : Here `.` is interpreted as all variables except `y` in the data frame used in fitting the model. It is equivalent to the linear combinations of predictor variables. For example `y ~ var1 + var2 + var3+...+var15`

**`y ~ . ^ 2`** will give all linear (main effects) and second order interaction terms of the variables in the data frame. It is equivalent to `y ~ var1 + var2 + ...+var15 + var1:var2 + var1:var3 + var1:var4...and so on`

**`y ~ var1 + var2 + ...+var15 + I(var1^2) + I(var2^2) + I(var3^2)...+I(var15^2)`** : Here I(var^2) indicates quadratic polynomial of one variable in the data frame.

**`y ~ poly(var1, degree = 2) + poly(var2, degree = 2)+...poly(var15, degree = 2)`**

or

**`y ~ poly(var1, var2, var3, ....var15, degree = 2)`** will be equivalent to the above expression.

**`poly(var1, degree = 2)`** is equivalent to **`var1 + I(var1^2)`**.

To get cubic polynomials, use `degree = 3` in `poly()`  or `I(var1^3)`.

There is a caveat in using `poly` versus `I(var, 2)`, which is after fitting the model, each of them will produce different coefficients, but the fitted values are equivalent, because they represent different parameterizations of the same model. It is recommended to use `I(var, 2)` over `poly()` to avoid the summary effect seen in `poly()`.

In summary, to get linear, quadratic and second order interaction terms, you will have an expression like

**`y ~ .^2 + I(var1^2) + I(var2^2)+...I(var15^2)`**

**Demo for four variables:**

```
old <- reformulate( 'y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4' )
new <- reformulate( " y ~ .^2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + I(x4^2) ")
tmp <- .Call(stats:::C_updateform, old, new)
tmp
# ~y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)^2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + I(x4^2)
# attr(,".Environment")
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE )

# ~y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x3^2) + I(x4^2) + 
#   x1:x2 + x1:x3 + x1:x4 + x2:x3 + x2:x4 + x3:x4
# attr(,"variables")
# list(~y, x1, x2, x3, x4, I(x1^2), I(x2^2), I(x3^2), I(x4^2))
# attr(,"factors")
#         x1 x2 x3 x4 I(x1^2) I(x2^2) I(x3^2) I(x4^2) x1:x2 x1:x3 x1:x4 x2:x3 x2:x4 x3:x4
# ~y       0  0  0  0       0       0       0       0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# x1       1  0  0  0       0       0       0       0     1     1     1     0     0     0
# x2       0  1  0  0       0       0       0       0     1     0     0     1     1     0
# x3       0  0  1  0       0       0       0       0     0     1     0     1     0     1
# x4       0  0  0  1       0       0       0       0     0     0     1     0     1     1
# I(x1^2)  0  0  0  0       1       0       0       0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# I(x2^2)  0  0  0  0       0       1       0       0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# I(x3^2)  0  0  0  0       0       0       1       0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# I(x4^2)  0  0  0  0       0       0       0       1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# attr(,"term.labels")
# [1] "x1"      "x2"      "x3"      "x4"      "I(x1^2)" "I(x2^2)" "I(x3^2)" "I(x4^2)"
# [9] "x1:x2"   "x1:x3"   "x1:x4"   "x2:x3"   "x2:x4"   "x3:x4"  
# attr(,"order")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
# attr(,"intercept")
# [1] 1
# attr(,"response")
# [1] 1
# attr(,".Environment")
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Comment: Thank you Sathish. I think that explains it all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1061/formula/29295/create-linear-quadratic-and-second-order-interaction-terms#t=201703220339030473396